# Error with importing a file upper in the directory #python3 #ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

Hi and hello(this is my first post here!).
I'm having this problem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/apzuba/Documents/Programowanie/FOLDER/Z/TES.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .. import ESE
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

This is my directory (a test environemnt):

/FOLDER

---ESE.py
---/Z

-----Z/TES.py

This is my code (TES.py):

```
from .. import ESE
print("gut")
```

I've tried all options that I could come up with, nothing works (each time there is this error, or

- "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'FOLDER'" if I use "from FOLDER import ESE"
- "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'FOLDER'" if I use "import FOLDER.ESE"
- "ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package" if I use "from ..FOLDER import ESE" or "from .FOLDER import ESE"

I'm stuck with this for over an hour, please help! I will appreciate much!

Comment: (1) How exactly are you running the code? (2) Do *FOLDER* and *Z* contain *\_\_init\_\_.py* files?

Comment: I am running them through terminal type: python3 TES.py (i am in Z folder directory). They do not contain these files.

Comment: So - try adding them.

Comment: Added. Now the directory looks like 

/FOLDER

---___init__.py

---ESE.py
---/Z
---___init__.py

-----Z/TES.py

It didn't work still, nevertheless.

Comment: In that case, see e.g. [Relative imports in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16981921/984421).